# Turn off colours temporarily for ansible ad-hoc commands

Tags: ansible, terminal

When I run an ansible (v2.9.9) ad-hoc command, the output is colourized. Green for successful resuilts etc. I am building up a bash pipeline, so how can I tell ansible to not colourize the output?

Comment: What do you mean by building up a pipeline? By default ansible does not colour is output when it is piped to another command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Configure [ANSIBLE_NOCOLOR](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-nocolor). For example

```
shell> ANSIBLE_NOCOLOR=True ansible localhost -a "date"
localhost | CHANGED | rc=0 >>
Wed 15 Jul 2020 10:03:04 AM CEST
```